GitHub Pages is not updating from custom workflow
I've been trying to use custom workflow to deploy a webpage using GitHub Pages. Here is my workflow:
name: Fetch, build and deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab of the repository
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Fetching branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.1
        with:
          ref: main

      - name: Installing Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: "3.9"

      - name: Installing requirements.txt
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Compile Flask/Jinja files
        run: python index.py build

      - name: Deploy
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.3
        with:
          branch: gh-pages
          folder: public
          clean: true

I have set up the source to "GitHub Actions", the workflow runs successfully, but my website only shows the README.md file of my repo. Here is my files and folders structure in my main branch:

But when I check the created gh-pages branch it looks like this:

I'm using the following Python script (index.py) to generate the website:
import sys
import json

from jinja2_static import Builder

build = Builder()
argument = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else None

with open("./static/data/commands.json", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
    commands = json.load(f)

build.generate(
    debug=False if argument == "build" else True,
    URL="chriszethird.github.io",
    commands=commands,
    output_folder="./public"
)

commands.json is a file containing commands name and description for my Discord bot that I display in a table on one of the pages. The different pages are stored in the templates\ folder by the way, and I'm currently not using a custom domain name so CNAME is empty.

'I have setup the source to "Github action"' - but that's not how JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action does it; as you're seeing, that sets up a branch-based deploy. This is explicitly called out in its docs: "You must configure your repository to deploy from the branch you push to. ..."

I assume I have to use the gh-pages branch then, not the main?

As a starting point you have to set the source to Deploy from a Branch at all, not GitHub Actions. Then you have to tell it which branch you want to deploy, which defaults to gh-pages.

Yeah so, I use the branch to deploy the website, and the action (custom workflow) will update that branch whenever I update the main branch (commit/push whatever I want). That makes more sense, thanks !

Should have read the doc as @jonrsharpe suggested. I had to set the deploy to branch, and select the gh-pages branch. Works like a charm now!
